# Is the Factory Method Pattern more flexible than Simple Factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I've been reading the book [Head First: Design Patterns](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch04.html), which I have found to be a good introduction to design patterns. However, I've got a question about a claim they make in Chapter 4:

They define the "Simple Factory" pattern as follows (Java pseudocode):

```
public abstract class Product
{
// Product characteristics
// Concrete Products should subclass this    
}
public class SimpleFactory {
    public Product createProduct(){
        // Return an instance of some subclass of Product
    }
}
public class Store {
    SimpleFactory factory;
    public Product orderProduct(){
        Product product = factory.createProduct();
        // Do some manipulation on product
        return product;
    }
}
```

The "Factory Method" is defined as follows (class Product remains the same and is omitted):

```
public abstract class Store {
//Concrete Stores must subclass this and override createProduct()
    public abstract Product createProduct();

    public Product orderProduct(){
        Product product = createProduct();
        // Do some manipulation on product
        return product;
    } 
}
```

Then the authors go on to claim that the Factory Method Pattern is much more flexible than Simple Factory, because while Simple Factory is "a one shot deal, with Factory Method you are creating a framework that lets the subclasses decide which implementation should be used" (page 135).

Now I don't get why this is true. The way I see it, Simple Factory is, in some senses, slightly **more** flexible than Factory Method: you can subclass the Simple Factory (instead of subclassing the Store) to get essentially the same behavior. You can even change the behavior at runtime if you wish! The only disadvantage of Simple Factory I could think of is when the product creation depends on state variables of the Store class: is this what the authors are calling flexibility, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right: author's assumption has been that you are not going to subclass `SimpleFactory`, which is not a fair assumption to make (unless `SimpleFactory` is marked `final`).

Since `SimpleFactory` is not final, you can definitely subclass it, gaining more flexibility than with a factory method, because `SimpleFactory` replaces inheritance with composition.

An even better approach would be making `SimpleFactory` an interface. Doing so would let you pick composition or inheritance according to your preference, because an interface would not limit you in cases when your `Store` class already inherits a class.

```
public interface SimpleFactory {
    Product createProduct();
}
```

Then you can use either composition

```
public class FactoryImpl implements SimpleFactory {
    public Product createProduct(){
        // Return an instance of some subclass of Product
    }
}
public class StoreComposition {
    SimpleFactory factory = new FactoryImpl();
}
```

or inheritance/composition combo

```
public class StoreInheritance implements SimpleFactory {
    SimpleFactory factory = this;
    public Product createProduct(){
        // Return an instance of some subclass of Product
    }
}
```

Comment: It's funny, they seem to consider subclassing SimpleFactory first; then they discard the approach because of lack of quality control (they were using a pizza store analogy throughout the chapter). Later they simply state that factory method is a framework that allows for much more flexibility than Simple Factory. Anyway, thanks for your answer! The inheritance/composition combo is somewhat strange, but it sure is super flexible!

Comment: If you subclass the simple factory, I believe you're heading to the Abstract Factory pattern. Simple factory has been called by Larman in his *Applying UML and Patterns* book as "a simplification of the Abstract Factory pattern." Also, if you keep reading in Head First, you'll find a section called **Is that a Factory Method lurking inside the Abstract Factory?**
Freeman, Eric; Robson, Elisabeth; Bates, Bert; Sierra, Kathy (2004-10-25). Head First Design Patterns (Kindle Location 2319). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Factory, you write a class, which provides very powerful encapsulation, but to do only one thing: encapsulating the creation and underlying type of an object. While, Factory Method pattern takes the full advantage of this class: it does what Simple Factory does, **besides**, it also encapsulates the create-process to not only create a "raw new object", but an deliverable / fully-equipped result, that's why it called `orderProduct` not just `createProduct`.

In short, the point of Factory Method is method that uses a Simple Factory. So if you think Factory Method is less flexible, that's because Factory Method does more things!