# Simple Factory with reflection C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

Simple factory using reflection involves storing (registering) various type names with their corresponding class type in a hash table, then using this hash table for generating objects in the factory.

```
interface Product
{
    void foo();
}
class ProductFactory
{
    HashTable m_RegisteredProducts = new HashTable();
    public void registerProduct(string productID, Type p)    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.add(productID, p);
    }

    public Product createProduct(string productID){
        return (Product) new m_RegisteredProducts[productID];
    }
}
```

I'm not clear on when does the process of registering a new type happen since all types to be used are to be loaded into the hash table at runtime. Where is the call to registerProduct() to be made?

1. Calling registerProduct() for all different classes at a single place inside ProductFactory class doesn't make sense since it would defeat the purpose of using reflection over naive switch/case method.
2. If registerProduct() is called inside the class definition of all classes implementing the interface, then an instance of the class is created **after/using** the Factory hence will always give an error.

Comment: Factory should produce instance. Shouldn't take the instance(as you're doing).

Comment: This is a pseudocode, thanks for pointing out the confusion. I'll make changes.

Comment: You are using a Simple Factory aka Concrete Factory, not a Factory Method pattern.  See the difference in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511823/is-the-factory-method-pattern-more-flexible-than-simple-factory Simple Factory is not really a design pattern (it's a programming idiom) and is definitely not the [tag:factory-pattern] since no "subclasses decide which class to instantiate."

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do reflection as it's expecting an *instance* implementing the `Product` interface, not a type. You would need `addProduct` to take a `Type` instance, check if it implements the `Product` interface, then dynamically create instances of it in `createProduct` (using something like `type.GetConstructor(<constructor signature>).Invoke(<arguments>);`)

Here's an article I wrote a long time ago on something similar: http://blixt.org/2009/06/05/getting-types-implementing-class-or-interface

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Calling registerProduct() for all different classes at a single place inside ProductFactory class doesn't make sense since it would defeat the purpose of using reflection over naive switch/case method.

Reflection is useful when extended product classes are added into a location (say a plug-ins directory). You have a list of strings to identify the supported plug-ins that can either be defined in a text file (application properties, which provides an added layer of security) or by (via reflection) scanning said plug-ins directory (less secure if someone can drop a hacked product in there). Disclaimer: I've never done this in C#, but it works well in Java. Apart from new product code and eventually modifying the properties file, there is no modification to the application code.

> 2. If registerProduct() is called inside the class definition of all classes implementing the interface, then an instance [of] the class is created after/using the Factory hence will always give an error.

I'm not sure that's always the strategy of the code in your question (where is it from?). You might want to read more about the different strategies of reflection combined with simple factory at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37547/Exploring-Factory-Pattern

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There are different scenarios that call for different strategies.
One strategy that I saw quite often if all product types are defined in the same assembly (or a list of assemblies) you could call something like this:

```
var productTypes= from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IProduct));
```

and then call registerProduct() for every element in productTypes.

Comment: This is the code for "scanning a plug-ins directory" I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30384825/1168342), and registering them.